# how can i assign a specific time (e.g 12:00) to a variable in shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I've been trying to assign a time which is (00:00) to a variable in my script but it just give me this error below

a brief description about my code:
my scripts must check the system time. Once the time reaches 12:00 AM, the current script will be calling another script.

```
function checkTime(){
while [ : ] 
do 
    time= "00:00"
    currentTime= $( date -d +"%H:%M")
    if [ "$currentTime" = "$time" ] ;
    then
    echo $(./Performance.sh)
fi
done 
}
```

The error that appeared:

```
line 5: 00:00: command not found
date: invalid date ‘+%H:%M’
```

Comment: Please always use https://www.shellcheck.net on your scripts. It'll catch a lot of common mistakes for you.

Comment: Thanks! but the same error is still apearing

Comment: linux? you can use `crontab`. Just add one line to `crontab -e`: `00 0 * * * /your/command`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the space between time= and "00:00" like such:

From

```
time= "00:00"
```

to:

```
time="00:00"
```

Bash is very picky on spaces.

P.S. Do the same for currentTime.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work**

```
function checkTime(){
while [ : ] 
do 
    time="00:00"
    currentTime=$( date +"%H:%M")
    if [ "$currentTime" = "$time" ] ;
    then
    echo $(./Performance.sh)
fi
done 
}
```

**Changes**

1. remove spacing between variable initialization.
2. use `date +"%H:%M"` instead of `date -d +"%H:%M"` -d option changes to string, %H:%M already prints in string so no need.

Comment: it worked!! thanks, but i want it to exit the loop after this line echo $(./Performance.sh), how?

Comment: `break` after line `echo $(./Performance.sh)` will break the loop when your condition is satisfied.